# Select sup name from same user table same user id t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called userstbl that has supId (supervisor) and has also userID with relation: one to many -> supid has many userid (same table).

```
ex. 
- uid:1 
  name: john
  supid:
...... 
- uid:2 
  name: smith
  supid: 1
```

How do I get all users grouped by supervisor name? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table with itself. In order to do that you will need to alias the table. Something like

```
select sup.name, usr.name
from userstbl usr
left join userstbl sup
on sup.userId = usr.supId
order by sup.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select s.supname 'Suppervisor',u.name 'User'
from tblSup s inner join tblUser u on s.supId=u.supid
order by s.supname
```

Comment: This will work too, except that if when there are  some null records without supervisor. thanks